# Merge Multi-Index Pandas Data Frames

Tags: python, pandas

I have three multi-index Pandas data frames -

```
df1 = {('parity', np.nan): {('20194', 1990): 0.3333333333333333,
                            ('22204', 1990): 0.0,
                            ('24060', 1990): 0.3333333333333333},
       ('parity', 0.0): {('20194', 1990): 0.0,
                         ('22204', 1990): 0.0,
                         ('24060', 1990): 0.3333333333333333},
       ('parity', 1.0): {('20194', 1990): 0.3333333333333333,
                         ('22204', 1990): 1.0,
                         ('24060', 1990): 0.0},
       ('parity', 2.0): {('20194', 1990): 0.3333333333333333,
                         ('22204', 1990): 0.0,
                         ('24060', 1990): 0.3333333333333333},
       ('education', 0.0): {('20194', 1990): 0.3333333333333333,
                            ('22204', 1990): 0.6666666666666666,
                            ('24060', 1990): 0.6666666666666666},
       ('education', 1.0): {('20194', 1990): 0.6666666666666666,
                            ('22204', 1990): 0.3333333333333333,
                            ('24060', 1990): 0.3333333333333333}}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = df1)
```

[image]

```
df2 = {('parity', 'zip'): {0: '20194', 1: '22204', 2: '24060'},
       ('parity', 'year'): {0: 1990, 1: 1990, 2: 1990},
       ('parity', 'parity'): {0: 1.5, 1: 1.0, 2: 1.0}}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = df2)
```

[image]

```
df3 = {'parity': {('20194', 1990): 1.5, ('22204', 1990): 1.0, ('24060', 1990): 1.0},
       'education': {('20194', 1990): 0.6666666666666666,
                     ('22204', 1990): 0.3333333333333333,
                     ('24060', 1990): 0.3333333333333333}}
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data = df3)
```

[image]

How do I merge all the data frames on the `zip` and `year` indexes and columns, such that they look like the image below?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with `MultiIndex` with levels `zip` and `year` in index and `MultiIndex` with 2 levels in columns:

```
#convert columns to MultiIndex in index
df2 = df2.set_index([('parity','zip'),('parity','year')])
#created new MultiIndex in columns
df3.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df3.columns, ['new']])
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3],axis=1).rename_axis(['zip','year'])
print (df)
              parity                               education           parity  \
                 NaN       0.0       1.0       2.0       0.0       1.0 parity   
zip   year                                                                      
20194 1990  0.333333  0.000000  0.333333  0.333333  0.333333  0.666667    1.5   
22204 1990  0.000000  0.000000  1.000000  0.000000  0.666667  0.333333    1.0   
24060 1990  0.333333  0.333333  0.000000  0.333333  0.666667  0.333333    1.0   

                education  
            new       new  
zip   year                 
20194 1990  1.5  0.666667  
22204 1990  1.0  0.333333  
24060 1990  1.0  0.333333
```